# Do references have types in Java/C# but not in Python?

Tags: java, python, reference, programming-languages

From Python in a Nutshell:

> In Python, **a variable or other reference has no intrinsic type**. The
>   object to which a reference is bound at a given time always has a
>   type, but a given reference may be bound to objects of various types
>   in the course of the program’s execution.

In Java and C#, where references are also used to refer to objects, do references have types?

If yes,

- what is the reason for that difference between Java/C# and Python?
- What is the consequence of the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a question about the design decisions in programming languages seems to be more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Comment: What chepner said. Also see [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Comment: Yes, references have types in Java and C# because they're *statically typed* languages. It means that the type checking is performed during compilation. Python performs type checking during runtime, so it is a *dynamically typed* language.